# Indexes on a table database

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I will have to insert 1 billion codes into an SQL Server Database table.
I'll be using BULK INSERT for this.
My question is: Should I create the indexes before or after inserting the data? I need the quickest option

Comment: why not benchmark the two options with 100'000 codes?

Answer (score 2):

1 billion records into a single table?  Ouch.  If you are dealing with data volumes on that level and you have to ask this question on a forum then you may be out of your element.  You should create the index after the insert but make sure that statistics are updated on the table after the insert.  The index will work against you if statistics are not up to date.

Comment: "If you are dealing with data volumes on that level and you have to ask this question on a forum" so true. Databases with that number of records are extremely tricky to get to operate well, only an experienced specialist really has the knowledge. If the person isn't working somewhere with a specialist of that type to learn from, he is almost ceratainly in over his head.

Answer (score 2):

When there are indexes on the table during an insert, the server will need to be constantly re-ordering/paging the table to keep the indexes up to date. If you drop the indexes, it can just add the rows without worrying about that, and then build the indexes all at once when you re-create them.

Read about [Bulk Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).

Also refer to:

[bulk insert with or without index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350003/bulk-insert-with-or-without-index)

Answer (score 1):

Create indices before.
BULK INSERT takes care of optimizing the indexing.

edit: this seems to be only true if the input data is ordered by the index. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx :

> ORDER ( { column [ ASC | DESC ] } [
>   ,... n ] )
>
> Specifies how the data in the data
>   file is sorted. Bulk import
>   performance is improved if the data
>   being imported is sorted according to
>   the clustered index on the table, if
>   any

Comment: Really? Creating indices beforehand is optimal on MsSQL-server? Other engines I've run into demonstrate the exact opposite. Do you have any info on why it is so? I'd be very interested in hearing about the internals.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment. If you wanted to insert that amount of data into Postgres you make sure to do the following: 1. create the table in the same transaction as the inserts happening (using COPY) if the table does not already exist AND 2. create the indices after the data has been inserted.  Creating the table in the same transaction as you do the inserts make sure that the engine will skip the write-ahead log. In any case; if the table exist or not you would wait until after the insert with creating the indices.

Comment: I thought I read it in the docs. I just rechecked, and it seems to only apply to a special case: The bulk insert got an "ORDER" option which will improve performance if the input data is ordered by the index.